Error with @SQLRestriction in Hibernate: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint"
I'm encountering an issue when using the @SQLRestriction annotation in my Hibernate entity. My goal is to filter out inactive records by adding a restriction that only loads entities where is_active = 'true'. However, when I add this annotation to my entity, I receive a DataIntegrityViolationException related to a primary key constraint when trying to insert a new record as part of another entity.
Here is the relevant part of my entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_type")
@SQLRestriction("is_active = 'true'")
public class TType {

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private TargetTypeName name;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "targetTypes")
    private Set<BusinessUnit> businessUnits = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}

The error message I receive:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 't_typePK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.t_type'. The duplicate key value is (BRAND_A).]; SQL [null]; constraint [insert into t_type (is_active,name) values (?,?)]

Additional context:
This error occurs when I try to save an entity BUnit, which has a ManyToMany relationship with TType. The relationship is defined as follows:
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(name = "ttypes_bunit",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "b_unit")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "t_type")})
@SQLJoinTableRestriction("is_active = true")
private Set<TType> tTypes = new LinkedHashSet<>();

My understanding:
I expected the @SQLRestriction to apply only to SELECT queries, filtering out records that do not meet the is_active = 'true' condition. However, it seems to be interfering with the INSERT operation, causing this primary key violation error. I suspect the issue might be related to the way the @SQLRestriction interacts with the ManyToMany relationship, especially in conjunction with @SQLJoinTableRestriction.  If I remove @SQLRestriction
tests are working with no issues. I also tried to add @SQLJoinTableRestriction("is_active = true") to the field in BUnit class, but this didn't help as well.
My question:

Why is the @SQLRestriction causing this DataIntegrityViolationException during an INSERT operation?

How can I correctly apply a filter for is_active while avoiding issues with INSERT operations, particularly in the context of ManyToMany relationships?


Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

You might be mistaken on the cause. Yes, your restriction interferes with selects. Your issue though is that you are using a non-unique ID - one that exists and has the is_active flag set to false - in your object model that you are then trying to persist. Since JPA cannot read the existing entity, it cannot find that it already exists, and so will insert it (assuming you are using merge). Look at the TType entity instances involved in the transaction and it should be more clear. What you want to happen depends - what exactly are you trying to do with this entity?

@Chris Hey, appreciate your comment! It's been a real eye-opener and has given me a better grasp on the underlying issue. So, in my particular situation, I reckon I should find a way to instruct Hibernate to overlook entities with is_active=false. It seems that adding SQLInsert to the TType entity and specifying a Merge condition could do the trick. I'll gladly accept your response as the solution if you post it as answer.
